# Массивы и строки

Tags: pascal

Есть задача:

Дан текст (массив символьных строк), каждый символ которого может быть буквой, цифрой или одним из знаков +, -, *. Подсчитать число вхождений буквы  f   в первые три группы букв.

Решить нужно на pascal.

С числами еще понятно. А вот с символами. Не соображу, как заполнить массив случайным образом, чтобы были, и буквы, и цифры, и знаки +, -, *. При этом параметры массива нужно, чтобы определялись с клавиатуры. Все это должно быть в двух процедурах. Одна для ввода матрицы. Вторая для вывода матрицы на экран. Или такой возможности в Паскаль нет? Тогда лучше вводить строки с клавиатуры?

Потом подсчет в первые три группы букв. Это имеется ввиду, что в строке может быть например, пять слов, разделенных пробелами, и поиск буквы f выполнить только в первых трех словах. Я правильно поняла?

Как же это можно реализовать?

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример, а то со вчерашнего дня мозги с этой задачей уже на бекрень:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгенерировать массив, состоящий из случайных строк, можно разными способами: задать алфавит, из которого будет состоять каждая строка или выбирать случайный символ по коду из кодировки. Я использовал первый способ.

```
Const
  N0=100; (* число элементов массива и массив-алфавит *)
  Alf: Array[0..38] Of Char = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
     'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
     'x', 'y', 'z', '+', '-', '*', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
     '8', '9');

Var
  StrMas: Array[0..N0-1] Of String;
  i, j, n, l: Byte;
  AlfInd: 0..38;

begin
  Repeat (* проверочка ввода числа элементов *)
    Write('N = ');
    ReadLn(N);
  Until (N In [1..99]);

  Dec(N); (* вычитаю 1 (N:=N-1; - то же самое) *)
  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To N Do (* мотаю цикл от 0 до число элементов - 1 *)
    Begin
      StrMas[i]:=''; (* элемент сначала равен пустому символу *)
      l:=Random(50)+1; (* случайная длина строки, но не меньше 1 *)
      For j:=1 To L Do (* мотаю цикл от 1 до длины будущей строки *)
        StrMas[i]:=StrMas[i]+Alf[Random(38)]; (* заполняю случайными элементами *)
    End;

(* вывожу массив *)
  For i:=0 To N Do
    WriteLn(StrMas[i]);

  WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!!!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

А вторая часть задания требует дополнительных пояснений: в задаче не указано, что в строках могут быть пробелы, поэтому группа букв, скорее всего, что-то другое: элемент массива, или определённое количество символов (заранее известное), или что-то ещё.

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно. "Дан текст..." - он вводится с клавиатуры или генерируется случайным образом?

Кстати генерировать очень просто - создаем строку типа "abcdefghij...yz0123456789+-*   " (там несколько пробелов в конце), генерируем случайное число от 0 до количества символов в этой строке, вынимаем символ с этим случайным номером и добавляем к результирующей строке. Чтобы повысить вероятность что у нас будет несколько групп-слов, делаем несколько пробелов)

Какие параметры должны определяться с клавиатуры (как там это в паскале... readln?).

Код не напишу, давно уже паскаля не касался. Но самый примитивный алгоритм вполне может быть такой:

Перебираем символы в данной строке от первого до конца, каждый символ сравниваем с пробелом и буквой f, каждый пробел и букву, разумеется, считаем. Если встретился третий пробел, значит выходим из цикла. В общем-то и все.

Answer (score 1):

Ну массив заполнить можно просто

```
Var mas:array['-','+','*','a','b'....,'0']; // синтаксис ей богу не помню, давно было.
Begin
randomize;
// ну тут когда заполняешь строки просто впиши 
for i=:0 to len(mas) do
 begin
rnd:=random(2)// от 0 до 2
stroka[i]:=mas[rnd]; // добавим в строку символ по рандому.
end;

// ну и ты их чередуй или сделай один массив с числами буквами и этими символами и юзай один массив.
End.
```

Дальше просто проверяй в цикле те условия которые нужны.